# How to get UTF-8 in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

How do I get UTF-8 support on my API?
At the moment, a string outputs like this:

```
name: "John D�m"
```

Instead of:

```
name: "John Döm"
```

Checkout app.js below:

```
var express = require('express'),
    driver = require('./driver');

var app = express();

app.configure(function () {
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
});

app.get('/drivers', driver.findAll);

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Up: http://127.0.0.1:3000/');
```

Comment: All strings in JS are UTF8 unless explicitly set to something else, so it is hard to say where your error would be coming from. What does `driver` do? The code you've provided is standard boilerplate and doesn't really help.

Comment: `driver` grabs all drivers from a mongoDB and prints all data out. See link here: http://xn--billstrm-t4a.se:1337/

Comment: @loganfsmyth `driver = require('./driver');` Is pretty much the same as this one: https://gist.github.com/ccoenraets/3819468#file-wines-js

Comment: My guess would be that the data in your DB is not UTF8. How did you populate the DB?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Hook into you response generator or create a middleware that does the following:

```
res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

Otherwise the browser displays the content in it's favorite encoding.

If this doesn't help you DB is probably in the wrong encoding.

**For older node.js versions** use:

```
res.header("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

Comment: `res.charset = 'utf-8'` is the same thing, right? I find it cleaner

Comment: res.charset did not work for me (nodejs 0.10.8) but this json-style worked : http://pastebin.com/NwcVEAra

Comment: Is this answer still correct? ...I'm having a hard time in my code... I keep getting � marks...

Comment: @D.Tate answer is still correct. The 'utf-8' depends on the encoding of your datasource.

Comment: Hi, I do not use a DB and want to avoid using with writeHead but I get `TypeError: res.header is not a function`error. Then solved this problem with this: `res.setHeader('content-type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8');` text/html part is about my code, it works with application/json

Answer (score 1):

I can't solve this problem with setting content type. I solved this problem with encode function.

```
res.cookie('someCookie', someCookie, {
  encode: c => c,
});
```

For more information: [express cookie](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.cookie)

ExpressJS version: 4.16.4

Answer (score -4):

My problem solved with this:

`res.writeHeader(200 , {"Content-Type" : "text/html; charset=utf-8"});`

Comment: This could lead to problems, if you want to return content but an HTTP status code other then `200`.