# Umlauts broken when doing get request

Tags: node.js, http, httprequest, http-get, diacritics

I'm trying to query a webservice which answers with plain text. The text often has german [umlauts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umlaut_%28diacritic%29) in it. In the received stream the umlauts are broken. Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Regards,
Torsten

Here is the sample code:

```
var request = require('request');        
var uri = <anUriWithUserId>;        
request(uri, {encoding: 'utf8','content-type': 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8'}, 
    function (error, response, body) 
    {
        console.log("encoding: " + response.headers['content-encoding']);
        console.log("type: " + response.headers['content-type']);
        console.log(body);
    });
```

And the response:

```
encoding: undefined
type: text/plain

error=0
---
asin=
name=Eistee
detailname=Pfanner Der Gr�ne Tee, Zitrone - Kaktusfeige, 2,0 l
vendor=Hermann Pfanner Getr�nke GmbH, Lauterach, �sterreich
maincat=Getr�nke, Alkohol
```

Comment: It is not the terminal, because `console.log('üäö');` works great

Comment: Possible answer: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267274/how-to-get-utf-8-in-node-js)

Comment: maybe it's just a typo but `content-type` is not supposed to be in quotes...

Answer (score 0):

When you set the `encoding` option in your request call, you advise the request module to decode the response body with this encoding. In this way you ignore the encoding used by the webservice, wich may or may not be utf-8. You need to find out wich encoding was used be the webservice and use that.

Depending on how complient the webservice you could also try to set the `Accept-Charset: utf-8` header.

As your output shows, the webservice doesn't provide the used encoding in the Content-Type header, which is a bad habbit imho.

Sidenote: Content-Encoding isn't for charset, but for compression, gzip migh be a valid value for it.