# Japanese text not visible in mobile

Tags: javascript, node.js, text, sms, clickatell

I am sending text message having Japanese characters.

Here is my message

In japanese

```
このOTPを使用してQuikドライブにログインします。 このOTPを誰とも共有しないでください
```

In English

```
use this OTP to login to Quik Drive. Please don't share this OTP to anyone
```

Here what I am getting

[**Here what I am getting on my mobile phone**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLXzf.jpg)

Here is my nodejs code

```
class ClickatellService {
  constructor() {
    this.sendSms('+mobileNumber', 'このOTPを使用してQuikドライブにログインします。 このOTPを誰とも共有しないでください')
  }

  sendSms(to, message) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      request.get(
        `https://api.clickatell.com/http/sendmsg?user=XXX&password=XXX&api_id=XXX&to=${to}&text=${encodeURI(
          message
        )}`,
        (error, response, body) => {
          if (error) {
            return resolve(error)
          } else {
            return resolve(response)
          }
        }
      )
    })
  }
}
```

What I can do to be getting the message in simple japanese language.

Any help would be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to set the charset to UTF-8 before sending.
I don't know what the actual charset your'e using in your code but make sure its UTF-8.

If you already using UTF-8, make sure the actual Font you using is able to handle the Japanese letters.

For more explanation on how to handle Japanese letters, maybe you should check this:

https://www.kanjidatabase.com/japanese_developer_tips.php

Comment: Thank you sir for the answer. I am not using any charset. I have tried using UTF-8 but did not work. Could you show how can I do that using nodejs

Comment: @Profer have a look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267274/how-to-get-utf-8-in-node-js

There's already explained answer.

Comment: Can you please check your phone or the phone who receive this sms, can handle the Japanese letters as the Font used.
I read about some old Android OS can't handle Japanese / Chinese letters properly.
If you for example change the OS language to Japanese, do you get the same result?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Unicode to send non GSM characters via SMS and then also set the unicode parameter.

Here is a PHP example:

```
$converted = iconv(
    "UTF-8", 
    "UCS-2BE", 
    "このOTPを使用してQuikドライブにログインします。 このOTPを誰とも共有しないでください"
);

$sms_data = urlencode(bin2hex($converted));

http://api.clickatell.com/....text=$sms_data&unicode=1
```

NOTE: Unicode messages are generally shorter than non-unicode messages, so be careful as you may pay for more than one message, detailed info over here:

https://archive.clickatell.com/developers/api-docs/concatenation-advanced-message-send/

Snippet:

70 (16-bit) characters allowed in a single SMS message part
67 (16-bit) characters used per message part when sending concatenated messages

Comment: Hi Sorry for the late reply but this does not work. It throws an error `TypeError: iconv is not a function
`

Comment: Then you need to install iconv or get something similar. The point is that you need to convert to a different character set.